# Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, x-frame-options

**Update: This works for IE but Chrome is still throwing this error.**
I am attempting to i-frame a site I own by another site I own. Here is error message I am getting in the JS console on Chrome:

```
Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('AllowAll, SAMEORIGIN, AllowAll') encountered when loading 'http://subdomain.mysite.com:8080/Dir/'. Falling back to 'DENY'.
Refused to display 'http://subdomain.mysite.com:8080/Dir/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'AllowAll, SAMEORIGIN, AllowAll'.
```

I did a search for SAMEORIGIN everywhere I am not setting this ANYWHERE.

The main site is www.mysite.com and the other site is subdomain.mysite.com. Obviously same-origin policies keep me from doing this. 
So i have set the X-Frame-Options header on my subdomain.mysite.com to "AllowAll". On the begin-request method i have added this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("X-Frame-Options", "AllowAll");
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

on the page level I have added this:

```
<meta name="x-frame-options" content="allowall" />
```

In Javascript i have added this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.domain = "mysite.com";
</script>
```

I am running out of things to try... Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out MVC4 adds the header by itself (unsolicited). The only way to get around this was to explicitly remove the header.

```
Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
```

There may be a way to convince MVC4 not to do this but it did not service in my scores of Google queries.

Comment: I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255468/how-to-solve-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame-err). I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 22):

In my case it was the anti-forgery token that was adding the header. Adding this in Application_Start stopped it from adding it:

```
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
```

I then added [the X-Frame-Options in the web.config](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) as I needed the whole site to be in an IFrame.

Comment: Yep, me too...+1 for the time-savings

Comment: @MiketheTike I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53255468/how-to-solve-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame-err). I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Some further detail to to Mike the Tike's answer, this is added to the application_start method in global.asax.cs, where you'll need the using directive system.web.helpers

Answer (score 0):

IIS might be adding a second header after yours (you can see this by pressing F12 for Developer Tools in Chrome, attempt to load the page, then click Network, and right-click on the failed page to copy the response headers to have a look).

To stop IIS from adding the header:

- Run IIS Manager
- Select your website
- Double click the HTTP Response Headers for the application (or on older IIS, right click on the website, click Properties, then HTTP Headers)
- Then you can override or remove the extra header